# Possible to identify defunct process from pgrep

Tags: process, ps

I am using `pgrep` for a bunch of things, however I can't get `pgrep` to list if the process is defunct.

Running `ps` adds to the end of the item `<defunct>` but `pgrep` does not, is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pgrep` is not able to filter a process based on its state. Try:

```
ps axo pid,stat | awk '$2 ~ /^Z/ { print $1 }'
```

Comment: Thanks very much @cuonglm - that's ok  I don't want to filter it, I just needed to identify it. Is running ps on the pid's returned from grep the only way? The reason I was avoiding ps is because ps doesn't give process name, it only gives command. The `-l` of `pgrep` was what I was relying on.

Comment: @Noitidart: AFAICT, it's the only way, there's no stand alone standard tool to do the job.

Answer (score 3):

Some versions of `pgrep` (e.g., [`procps-ng`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html)) support a `--runstates Z` option.